# Simple sliding out jquery box not working

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to slide out my div with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/BVgzc/1/

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#country_slide").hide();
$("#country").show();

$('#country').click(function(){
$("#country_slide").slideToggle();
});
```

I can't understand why it isn't expanding and contracting when I click my link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)};`

See http://jsfiddle.net/uhEgG/

Depending on the browser you're using, you should take a look at the Console of the developer tools. It'll make your debugging much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your code wasn't properly formatted. I erased the `document ready` and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/BVgzc/2/